# Job Shop Scheduling Classification

Tags: reference-request, linear-programming, operations-research

I am searching for literature that might exist on my problem. I can't imagine that there is none.
I think i am just not hitting the right search terms.
Maybe someone knows what name my problem might belong to in the literature and is able to point me to it:

I have a standard Job shop Scheduling problem.

additionally:

One Machine in my shop consumes resources for certain types of jobs.

One Machine in my shop produces resources for certain types of jobs.

One may think of it like a Shop where you need a resource like a liquid to process a job  on a machine and after some jobs the liquid will be empty and has to be filled up by a process that is to be interjected.

I hope someone knows the right classification for my problem here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to leave it here if someone may find this post in search for the same thing.

The Keyword i needed to find the right literature was RCPSP - Resource Constrained Project Scheduling Problem.